# What will be the validation for the following schema uisng joi?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, validation, joi

What will be the validation for the following schema uisng joi?
I am trying to write a NodeJs Application. And i am trying to validate for the following schema but i don't know how to validate nested objects how can i do that?

```
const userSchema = {
    cart: {
        fn: () => [
            {
                id: {
                    fn: () => String,
                    option: {}
                },
                count: {
                    fn: () => Number,
                    option: {}
                }
            }
        ],
        option: {}
    },
    address: {
        contactName: {
            fn: () => String,
            option: {}
        },
        detailAddress: {
            line1: {
                fn: () => String,
                option: {}
            },
            line2: {
                fn: () => String,
                option: {}
            },
            line3: {
                fn: () => String,
                option: {}
            }
        },
        pin: {
            fn: () => Number,
            option: {}
        },
        country: {
            fn: () => String,
            option: {}
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean "what will be the validation"? As in how to rewrite this using Joi? The docs should give you all the info you need: https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.3.0

Comment: Yeah i don't know how to go about this kind of schemas. So the typical form input type of validation and this is different so. This is nested so i don't know how to go about that.